# Why does a NSTextField's field editor inherit the text color of it's target field when it's configured otherwise?

Tags: swift, cocoa

My `NSTextField`'s `textColor` is `white` and non-editable. When I click on the label, I set the `NSTextField` to `isEditable = true`. Performing a second click on the label places it into edit mode. I get a field editor etc.

Prior or editing it looks like this:

[image: step_1]

I am subclassing my `NSTextField` to configure that field editor like so:

```
override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    let value = super.becomeFirstResponder()

    if value == false {
        return value
    }

    if let fieldEditor = currentEditor() as? NSTextView {

        fieldEditor.backgroundColor = NSColor.white
        fieldEditor.drawsBackground = true
        fieldEditor.textColor = NSColor.black
    }


    return value
}
```

You can see from the code above I am setting the `textColor` of the field editor to `black`. When I enter editing mode I get the expected behavior:

[image: step_2]

So far so good. Enter the issue: Any new keystrokes are reflected as `white` text:

In the sample below I have highlighted the contents of the field to show the white text:

[image: step_3]

So it would seem that even though I am setting the `fieldEditor.textColor = NSColor.black` and I see that black color, the field editor is inheriting the `NSTextField`'s text color for new input?

If, in my editor configuration I do this, keep in mind this is in a NSTextField subclass:

```
fieldEditor.backgroundColor = NSColor.white
fieldEditor.drawsBackground = true
fieldEditor.textColor = NSColor.black
textColor = NSColor.black // <-------
```

Then text input while in editing mode does come though as black. I understand the field editor is a proxy to the `NSTextField`:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/TextEditing/TextEditing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009459-CH3-SW29

So is the flow:

- field editor shows
- becomes first responder
- has some kind of view for the first render
- sends keystrokes to the underlying `NSTextField`
- updates itself using the `NSTextField` settings?

Comment: The cell sets the typing attributes of the field editor (`NSTextView`) after `becomeFirstResponder` and `setUpFieldEditorAttributes`.

Comment: ah, so because it pulls it's settings from the cell last  it last, it wins. Your explanation explains the behavior to be sure  I wonder why they let you set the textColor of the field editor? It's just a NSTextView so why wouldn't they I suppose. Since the Field Editor is shared it does make sense that they would pull the cell attributes so it matches its target. You should submit that as an answer so I can accept it as THE answer.